# Applying Law of Large Numbers to Find Almost Sure Limit

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

I am working on the following problem:

Let $\xi_{1},\xi_{2},...$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $P(\xi_{i} = 2^i
) =
\frac{1}{2^i}$ and $ P(\xi_{i} = 0) = 1 − \frac{1}{2^i}$
, $i ≥ 1$. Find the almost sure value of the limit
$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\xi_{1}+...+\xi_{n})/n$.

This is clearly an application of the Law of Large Numbers, but how do I determine what the limiting value is?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: by the (first) Borel-Cantelli lemma, we can find $\Omega'$ of probability one such that for any $\omega\in\Omega'$, there exists an integer $N(\omega)$ for which $\xi_i(\omega)\neq 2^i$ for any $i\geqslant N(\omega)$. What does it imply for the sequence $\left(\xi_{i} (\omega)\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$?

Comment: You've answered this one previously :) See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1531771/215011